# JavaScript fetch inside loop in onSubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can organize my code that `console.log(url)` calls after `each` loop?

```
$("form").on('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const form = $("form");
    if (!form.checkValidity()) return;
    
    const formData = new FormData(form[0]);

    $(".file-upload-wrapper img.card-img").each(async function (i) {
        
        const src = $(this).attr("src");
        const fileName = $(this).attr("data-filename");

        const response = await fetch(src);
        const data = await response.blob();
        formData.append("file", data, fileName);
        
        console.log(src);   
    })

    const url = $(form).attr("action");
    console.log(url);    
})
```

Comment: wrap your console log url in a function inside your on submit and call it in the each loop. or place the console log url in the loop itself both would work just depends on what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` works inside `for..of` loops, not inside synchronous array methods like `.forEach()` and `.map()`. I suspect it doesn't work either inside jQuery's `$.each()`, because only the *inner* function is `async`; the outer code remains synchronous, so you are getting your last `console.log(url)` before anything else. Try with a `for...of` loop instead:

```
$("form").on('submit', async (e) => { // async here
    e.preventDefault();
    
    const form = $("form");
    if (!form.checkValidity()) return;
    
    const formData = new FormData(form[0]);

    const $images = $(".file-upload-wrapper img.card-img");
    
    for (let image of $images) {
        const $image = $(image);
        const src = $image.attr("src");
        const fileName = $image.attr("data-filename");
    
        const response = await fetch(src);
        const data = await response.blob();
        formData.append("file", data, fileName);
        
        console.log(src);   
    }

    const url = $(form).attr("action");
    console.log(url);    
});
```

Comment: I'd be delighted to know why somebody has downvoted my answer. What did I do wrong? Why do you think this answer is not valid? It would be more constructive and more helpful than just dumping a silent downvote and being on your way.